# In ansible, how do I specify an exclusion set of hosts in a playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

With command line patterns, you can specify patterns like "all,!ntpservers" but I can't figure out how to specify this in a playbook. I'm regularly running into cases where I have to install a client on all machines except the server.

Comment: What do you mean you can't figure out? You need to type it in. Alternatively please point to the line in the docs that makes it hard for you to understand. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/intro_patterns.html

Comment: you mean inside the playbook?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You specify the hosts for a playbook on the line that begins with `hosts:`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#basics):

> The `hosts` line is a list of one or more groups or host patterns, separated by colons, as described in the [Working with Patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/intro_patterns.html) documentation.

For example:

```
---
- hosts: all,!ntpservers
  tasks:
    # ... your tasks here
  roles:
    # ... etc etc etc
```

These roles and tasks will be appled to `all` hosts except `ntpservers`.

Comment: I'll add more detail to the question. This method ignores the !ntpservers on my installation of ansible 2.5.3.

Comment: @RobertRapplean Probably best if you post a new question. Changing the meaning of a question after it's been answered is a great way to confuse everyone.