# How to specify an exclusion pattern in an inventory file

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to define a group with an exclusion pattern, when defining this group in an inventory file?

```
group1:
  hosts:
    xxx-[1:100]:

group2:
  hosts:
    xxx-2:
    xxx-37:

# This should contain the hosts from group1 without the hosts from group2
group3:
  # Throws an error: "Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced"
  children: group1,!group2
```

Like in [In ansible, how do I specify an exclusion set of hosts in a playbook?](https://serverfault.com/a/922184/320971)
But I don't want to define the group logic in each playbook, I want to define it only once in the hosts file

Answer (score 1):

> *Is it possible to define a group with an exclusion pattern, when defining this group in an inventory file?*

As far as I understand [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html) that is something which is not possible, at least not out-of-box with core components. Maybe with [Inventory plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory.html) script ...

> *But I don't want to define the group logic in each playbook*

Leaving one with that as option only.

The [Patterns: targeting hosts and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_patterns.html)

> *let you run commands and playbooks against specific hosts and/or groups in your inventory*

and are not intended for the inventory itself.